# How to Extract a numeric value from the XML

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, report, fusion

I'm trying to create a `BI Publisher` report, I am using `HRC_TXN_DATA`, `HRC_TXN_HEADER`, `fa_fusion_soainfra.WFTASK` tables.

Here I am trying to extract a `GoalIdList` from a `XML` code which is in the data_cache column from `HRC_TXN_DATA` table.

I am using this code

```
XMLTYPE(txn_d.data_cache).EXTRACT('/TRANSACTION/TransCtx/GoalIdList/text()').getStringVal()
```

Note* I have already tried changing the `text()` to `int(),number()` still getting same error.

Here is the query I am using

```
 select 
wft.ASSIGNEESDISPLAYNAME,
txn_d.STATUS,
XMLTYPE(txn_d.data_cache).EXTRACT(s.column_value,'/TRANSACTION/TransCtx/GoalIdList/int()').getStringVal() Goal_id
from 
 fa_fusion_soainfra.WFTASK wft
 left outer join HRC_TXN_HEADER txn_h on wft.CORRELATIONID = to_char(txn_h.TRANSACTION_ID)
 left outer join HRC_TXN_DATA txn_d on txn_h.TRANSACTION_ID = txn_d.TRANSACTION_ID
```

I am getting this error

> oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: oracle.xdo.XDOException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272 ORA-06512: at line 1"

Comment: I think `CORRELATIONID` column is not `char` or `varchar2`, I think it's `number` or `integer` and you're joining it with `to_char`. This is your `line 272` of the package?

Comment: and you have the same error?

Comment: As you suggested I  replaced the query with

"select 
wft.ASSIGNEESDISPLAYNAME,
txn_d.STATUS,
XMLTYPE(txn_d.data_cache).EXTRACT('/TRANSACTION/TransCtx/GoalIdList/text()').getStringVal() Goal_id
from 
 fa_fusion_soainfra.WFTASK wft
 left outer join HRC_TXN_HEADER txn_h on wft.CORRELATIONID = txn_h.TRANSACTION_ID
 left outer join HRC_TXN_DATA txn_d on txn_h.TRANSACTION_ID = txn_d.TRANSACTION_ID
"
but now I getting different error

Comment: Here is the error message which I am getting 
 "oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: oracle.xdo.XDOException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number
"
I cannot understand what is the invalid number

Comment: ok, you've solved prev error, this error happens from your `select-s`. Try to comment one by one selects between `select` and `from`, try to compile query and you will find the issue

Comment: I think it's here: `XMLTYPE(txn_d.data_cache).EXTRACT(s.column_value,'/TRANSACTION/TransCtx/GoalIdList/int()').getStringVal()`)
find any documentation about input parameters during using such structure

Comment: Also you didn't told what you have at `line 272` of the package `SYS.XMLTYPE`

Comment: thank you for your reply, the problem is with XMLTYPE(txn_d.data_cache).EXTRACT(s.column_value,'/TRANSACTION/TransCtx/GoalIdList/int()').getStringVal()).

Comment: Do you have any info about this part? `EXTRACT(s.column_value,'/TRANSACTION/TransCtx/GoalIdList/int()')`. I think you should erase `s.column_value,` according to this [examples](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/xmltype-datatype)

Answer (score 0):

```
select xmlcast(xmlquery('/TRANSACTION/TransCtx/GoalIdList' passing xmltype(s.data_cache) returning content) as varchar2(40)) from s;
```

Comment: getting an error
"oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: oracle.xdo.XDOException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272 ORA-06512: at line 1"

Comment: please post sample xml to test it.